# wpf xaml designer bug

Tags: wpf, visual-studio-2010, designer

every time we open a *.xaml file in our project - we see not working designer and a lot of messages 'type not found' 'assembly not found' etc.
After a couple of experiments, i found out a root of a problem : 
create new WPF application, create a folder in project root, add some value converter to folder, try to use it on your 'MainWindow.xaml'

you will probably write something like this :

```
xmlns:Folder="clr-namespace:WpfApp.Folder"
```

and then

```
   <Window.Resources>
        <Folder:SomeValueConverter x:Key="someKey"/>
    </Window.Resources>
```

You know...

And, now the most interesting thing!
when you build your project for x86 or 'any CPU' - everything will be just fine, designer will be available, all namespaces will be imported perfectly!BUT, just change you project configuration to x64...Rebuild solution and open design view... You'll be amazed...errors, types not found, etc...
How the hell to use VS xaml designer in x64 applications?

Windows 7 enterprise x64, Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate

Comment: Aaaaand an example error would be.....

Comment: * Undefined CLR namespace. The 'clr-namespace' URI refers to a namespace 'WpfInteractive.Folder' that is not included in the assemblyError*The type 'Folder:SomeConverter' was not found. Verify that you are not missing an assembly reference and that all referenced assemblies have been built.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[Others have reported the same problem](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/vswpfdesigner/thread/3c641040-7726-4746-ba61-9cd8811fac99). One of the [workarounds](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/632407/wpf-designer-fails-when-self-referencing-project-assembly-in-xaml-in-64-bit-app-with-visual-studio-2010) suggested was to do the design work with a 32-bit target, and then switch to 64-bit only when you're ready to compile and deploy.

Comment: @C. Lawrence Wenham, any idea whether this issue has been solved? Switching targets each time I want to compile and run the code can't be the solution...

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I was using an obfuscator ([ConfuserEx](https://github.com/yck1509/ConfuserEx) to be exact) as a post-build step in Release configuration that was causing this behavior. Switching back to Debug configuration fixed the problem. Alternately, removing the post-build step will also fix the problem.