# WPF XAML editor error in Design time, But the application works fine in run time

Tags: wpf, xaml

In my daily work, I faced an issue regarding WPF XAML editor. For example, I will use [Dynamic Data Display](http://dynamicdatadisplay.codeplex.com/) in my project. Firstly, I will add the DynamicDataDisplay.DLL to my project. And then I will add a specific xmlns for this DLL. But I found there is no IntelliSense for the added DLL, I need typed the namespace manually. Here is the code.

```
<Window x:Class="WPFMonitor.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d3="http://research.microsoft.com/DynamicDataDisplay/1.0"
        Title="Monitor Window" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <TextBlock Text="CPU Usage" Margin="20,10,0,0"
                       FontSize="15" FontWeight="Bold"/>
            <TextBlock x:Name="cpuUsageText" Margin="10,10,0,0"
                       FontSize="15"/>
        </StackPanel>
        <d3:ChartPlotter x:Name="plotter" Margin="10,10,20,10" Grid.Row="1">
            <d3:ChartPlotter.VerticalAxis>
                <d3:VerticalIntegerAxis />
            </d3:ChartPlotter.VerticalAxis>

            <d3:ChartPlotter.HorizontalAxis>
                <d3:HorizontalIntegerAxis />
            </d3:ChartPlotter.HorizontalAxis>

            <d3:Header Content="CPU Performance History"/>
            <d3:VerticalAxisTitle Content="Percentage"/>
        </d3:ChartPlotter>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

As you can see, I have referenced the DLL in my XAML Code, but the editor give me the error about

> The type 'd3:ChartPlotter' was not found. Verify that you are not
> missing an assembly reference and that all referenced assemblies have
> been built.

When I clicked the reloaded the designer. I tested this issue on VS 2010 SP1/VS 2013 Update2. But if I build this application. No errors, and it runs OK.

I am not an English speaker. if you cannot understand my question. please feel free to let me know. I will clarify it.

Any help would be appreciated!
Thank You very much! :)

Comment: Have you checked [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5314627/wpf-xaml-designer-bug) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19374023/designer-not-able-to-show-xaml-the-type-local-was-not-found) ??

Comment: After you referenced the new dll have you build your solution completely ? The Designer Intellisense will therefore not work.

Comment: @Yuliam Chandra, Thank You for the quick reply. I tried the way provided by the links. But it doesn't work in my case.

Comment: @Mark, Yes, when I referenced the new dll, I have built my solution completely. I shared my sample on OneDrive. You can download from https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=6FF216CBAAA91C6%21350

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. A **possible solution** is get the source code if you can, and compile the .dll file yourself, then add it as a reference.

Worked for me in Visual Studio 15 when the .dll file I was using previously, was compiled in Visual Studio 13.

Hope it helps Someone :)